# Problems with routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application that has one purchase_order for each purchase_request.

My models are set up like so

**purchase_order.rb**

```
...
belongs_to :purchase_request
...
```

**purchase_request.rb**

```
...
has_one :purchase_order
...
```

My routes are set up like so:

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :purchase_requests do
    :purchase_orders
  end
```

and in my view I link to it like so:

```
<%= link_to "Purchase Order", new_purchase_request_purchase_order_path(@purchase_request) %>
```

and in my form I have:

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :purchase_request %>
```

but it is not loading the id of the purchase_request.  Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it but what I did:

in the **purchase_orders_controller** I placed:

```
...
def new
@purchase_request = PurchaseRequest.find(params[:purchase_request_id])
...
```

then in the **new** view i did:

```
<%= render 'form', :purchase_request_id=>@purchase_request.id %>
```

and last but not least, I put this in my **_form** partial:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :purchase_request_id, :value=>purchase_request_id %>
```

Comment: If you did `form_for [@purchase_request, @purchase_order]`, wouldn't your `purchase_request_id` already be in the `action` of the form? Then there's no need for the hidden field.

Comment: This did not work.  The [] return a syntax error and () do not load it in properly.   It just goes back to the purchase_requests page and displays the link to the purchase_order page (which goes away if it is created)

Comment: Hmm... that's what the docs say. Do you have a `@purchase_order` set? Also your nested route needs to say `resources :purchase_orders` to register properly. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for